# Change backslashes in Python 3.x

Tags: python, string, string-literals

How to replace `'\\\\'` with `'\\'` in Python?
For example: `"Shady \\\ vs \\\ everybody"` -----> `"Shady \ vs \ everybody"`.
I tried `r""`, and `\\` but it does not work...

Comment: I should take my string as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Use double backslash to match a single backslash character.

```
>>> s = r'Shady \\\ vs \\\ everybody'
>>> print(s.replace('\\\\\\', '\\'))
Shady \ vs \ everybody
```